# Checking for winner in Blackjack

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

My program is checking for a winner in my blackjack game after the user clicks "stand".
When I try calling the winner with AJAX, I want to see if there is a winner. If yes, then alert the winner. Else, allow the dealer to make his move. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Sample result/output after stand: User hand = dQ, hJ; val = 20 - alerts " wins! in stand"

Expected result after this hand: - go to ajaxDealer(user);

php code:
($checkPlayerHandValue works fine, i.e. if User has C5,HQ, will return 15)

```
function checkWinner($u, $d, $uValue) {
    if($uValue > 21)
        return $d;
}

if($checkPlayerHandValue > 0) {
    $checkPlayerHandValue = checkPlayerHandValue($user);
    $winner = checkWinner($user, $dealer , $checkPlayerHandValue);
}

 $row = mysql_fetch_array($checkNextTurn);
 $playerTurn = $row['user'];
 echo($playerTurn."|");
 echo($winner);
```

js code:

```
xmlhttpB.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttpB.readyState==4 && xmlhttpB.status==200) {
                elements = xmlhttpB.responseText.split("|");
                user = elements[0];
                winner = elements[1];
                //alert(winner);
                if(winner != "")
                    ajaxDealer(user);
                else 
                    alert(winner + " wins! in stand");              

            }
            clickButton = true;
        }
```

Comment: none that I have come across so far. Everything checks out. When the $winner leaves the php file, it is set to "", i.e. no winner yet

Comment: What's the problem then? Is the AJAX request returning what it needs to?

Comment: yes it is, but the javascript is not taking the proper action with what is returned (I modified my tags to included js as well for the question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do yourself a favor and start using the jQuery library with it's AJAX module.

As far as your question goes, can you tell us what the current problem with your code is (what is not happening that should be happening, or vice versa).

Also, I think this logic is incorrect:

```
if(winner != "")
   ajaxDealer(user);
else 
  alert(winner + " wins! in stand");
```

And should be flipped:

```
if(winner == "")
   ajaxDealer(user);
else 
  alert(winner + " wins! in stand");
```

Comment: As for your 1st comment, this is a final project for a class that we really didn't touch on jQuery. When I have time, I will probably go ahead and learn it. As for your 2nd comment, I stated above what is happening and what is not happening. In this specific example, there is NO WINNER and the function should automatically call the dealerHit() function. Instead, it alerts a winner, but since there is no winner, the statement in the alert reads " wins! in stand"

Comment: Alright, I see now your Sample, but it was kind of hard to read in that code block. Are you sure the AJAX request is going? Have you specified a URL? Try alert(xmlhttpB.responseText) to make sure you are getting something.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. Something is definitely coming back. I tried your suggestion and got back the 'user' + | + ""

Comment: Did that //alert(winner); that you commented out work? Did you try alert(user) ? Also, I think your logic is flipped (see answer edit)

Comment: yup, the alerts are all good. I also changed the php to return "notdone" if there's no winner to make it clearer. Something seems to be screwy about the if statement

Comment: i could've sworn I tried that and was getting the same messed up results. But if it's working now, I'm not going to complain. Thanks for working through this with me. I happen to have one other question not quite related to this but I think it may have to do with the order that AJAX calls things. Can we move this over to chat so I can ask you that question as well?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20985/discussion-between-hellohellosharp-and-gotguts)